# Can a Case close date be modified?

Tags: case, closedate

I have a case 
Case no :34765 
Close Date: 23/04/2015

Can i Change the case close date to 27/6/2015.

Comment: please refer this salesforce help article for details : https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Can-the-Closed-Date-on-a-Closed-Case-be-Changed&language=en_US

Answer (score 1):

No, this field is managed by the system and can never be modified by a user, even an administrator. As noted in the comment, you may request Create Audit Fields for an org, which allows you to insert false audit times and users, including Created By, Last Modified By, Created Date, Last Modified Date, and, for cases, Close Date.